# Should I extend my internship causing my academics to be delayed?

Tags: software-industry, internship

I am a senior CS student with only one semester left to go at college and I am currently working at an internship in a technology company for the summer. My boss offered to extend my internship but if I accept the offer I will have to brake my semester into two semesters so I have the time to work.

This is my second internship and the pay for the internship is pretty bad. Having said that, is it worth continuing to be an intern or should I decline the offer and go full time for my last semester and find a full time position in January?

Comment: In Texas, the average for a STEM internship was around $17-$18 an hour. I would try to get that raised. How many credit hours are you taking?

Comment: You are greatly underpaid if you are in STEM in California. That being said, questions asking for career advice are off topic here.

Comment: Hello user, I noticed you have a few closed questions on our site. Check out [ask] for some guidance on how to edit and word your posts. This will help you get the best answers as well as prevent them from being closed. You can go back and edit closed questions to clarify them, which bumps them back to the top for review.

Comment: In this case, can you give us more background about your specific situation? Otherwise, all we can do is give advice based on guesses, which is unlikely to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Unless the work you are doing is *really* good for your career, **finish your schooling and get a full time job.**

First off, you do not want to have to split your semester for two reasons: time and money. School is really expensive, and you don't want to have to pay for an additional semester.

Next ask yourself is the experience you will be gaining from staying is going to be extremely beneficial for your career. You have already worked there for the summer, **will working there for another 4+ months make your resume significantly stronger?** If you are in a situation where your resume is not strong enough to get you a job upon graduation but staying at this job longer will tip the scales, maybe think about staying, otherwise move on. I don't see a situation where this could be the case, you never know.

There are other options too, for example you could try [asking for a full time job at the company upon graduation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-a-fulltime-offer-after-the-end-of-my-internship?rq=1). This is pretty common in my school's internship program, with the majority of people getting job offers upon graduation. In your case, you might not want to consider this option unless they give you a rather large pay raise. It is not the purpose of this question, but try looking up online what is the standard pay range for the job you are looking for so you don't end up dreadfully underpaid.

ps. Your assumption about being paid better <strike>is</strike> should be correct...