# How to ask if a company is interested in keeping an intern on?

Tags: internship

I am a senior in college (computer science) and I will be graduating in December. I am currently at a 3 month summer internship for a company that I like but am not necessarily sold on. I have two weeks left here before going back to school. I have been considering working for a startup after school or even potentially moving if the right opportunity presented itself.

I know I will interview at other companies prior to accepting any position but I was wondering how I should ask my boss about how the company feels about me. I am also not sure if they are even looking to hire anyone full time in the near future so that was another part of what I would need to inquire about. They are easily the highlight of my resume experience so I want to make sure I don't end on any kind of sour note.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Actually, here's a better target to close both of these against: [Is it appropriate to ask for a fulltime offer after the end of my internship?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11978/17949)

Comment: The first link is basically what I was asking. I tried to search it and could not find it. I'm not sure if it matters which it is linked to if closed.

Comment: On the other hand I really like the answer you gave me and it seems more complete than the answers on the duplicate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Literally just ask them.** "Are you going to have any positions like X in time frame Y?" Where X and Y are *whatever you're looking for*. If they say no, well, there you go.

If they say yes, ask if you would be competitive for those positions. If they say well, we don't have X and Y, but we've got another opportunity you might be interested in, then you've got the ball rolling. It's not really a complicated conversation to have; just tell them what you're looking for. You're not going to surprise or shock them with the news that you, an intern about to graduate from school, *want a job*. To them, it's an incredibly mundane conversation, and one that you'll often be expected to initiate to show your interest.

I don't think I can ever recall a conversation with a recruiter or hiring manager who said their company doesn't want to ultimately hire its own interns. Even if you're not the most amazing, impressive intern, your experience represents an investment by the company that they would have to make all over again—with a greater commitment and expense—if they hire from outside their pool of interns. If you've done poorly enough in the internship that they're not at all interested in keeping you on (assuming they have an opening), you'll know it.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it from leaving on a high note. Thank the company for the opportunity and the internship, it was a great experience and you learned a lot. Also make note that you hope that any future opportunities arise when you graduate you'd greatly appreciate the opportunity to apply or be considered.

You don't have to make demands or ask, you can leave it open ended.