# Ensuring Full time offer from Internship

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, internship, fulltime

I am coming to the end of my 4 months internship at my company at the end of August. And I'd like to be (hopefully) promised/given a full-time offer once I graduate from university.

I have read [Is it appropriate to ask for a fulltime offer after the end of my internship?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-a-fulltime-offer-after-the-end-of-my-internship/11979#11979), but my situation is different. I've already asked the company's **Recruiter** about offer extension. He told me that there is no process about rehiring the interns after they graduate, but should inform my **Manager**, and contact the company again a few months prior to graduation.

Should I do as what my **Recruiter** told me? What are the best steps to take to ensure a full-timer offer be given to me now or in the near future? Ideally, I'd like to not have to reapply with resume/cover letter again to the company when I graduate, and just be "promised" that I can come back full time as soon as I graduate.

P.S: If it matters, my performance has been good during the internship. I got a reference letter from my supervisor.

Comment: Have you asked about possibility of openings at the company at your target time? I mean ask the company directly not a "recruiter" that has no personal interest in getting you with the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple: 1) Impress your Manager with your work, 2) Get good grades at your school (at least maintain 3.8 GPA); and 3) Keep in touch with the Manager/Managers. This is how I got my first job after my graduation.

Moreover, see other potential opportunities (teams) in the company and connect with the managers of those teams.

One more thing is that, if you did good work/project, then you can give a presentation at the end of your internship. Invite managers of the teams that you are interested to this presentation (once you were introduced to them).

Comment: I'm more interested in finding a way to see whether or not I can skip the process of reapplication for full time after graduation. Presentation to managers of teams is not realistic as they are extremely busy. Connecting to other managers could work, but I can't really see how that would result in me getting a fulltime offer before graduation. I already have a decent relationship with my current manager

Comment: No you can't skip reapplication. What you _can_ do is skip the first few stages of evaluation that can only say "no", by having someone inside the company willing to vouch for you.

Comment: How exactly would I go about skipping the first few stages of evaluation? I have a decent relationship with my supervisor, his reference letter. Would I simply contact the company's recruiter when the time comes? Do I still need to give a resume?

Comment: @Mantracker At least for big companies, you have to follow a procedure for getting a job. However, if your current manager is impressed with your work and there are openings relevant to your background, then he will recommend you for a position (anyway you need to fill a job application). Most likely you will get it -- it is like walking on a cake.

Comment: @samarasa So I guess what I need to do is do keep my contact with my manager/supervisor. When I will be reapplying, put my manager as reference. Maybe contact him by email to see if it is possible for him to put in some good words for me internally. BUT still follow the same method of application with resumes and interviews and stuff

Comment: What's the basis of your GPA figure?

Comment: @Brandin: My current employer. It is for fresh grads.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a note about IF there is an appropriate job opening.  Because all the rest won't help if they don't need another person at your level.

Comment: I thought presentations at the end of internships were common practice in the US?  Either way, I doubt you can skip any application steps, but your chances for getting hired are much higher since they already know your quality of work.