# When should I ask for a for a return full-time offer after being an intern for a year?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, hiring-process, new-hires, offer

I graduate at the end of this year and I've been started working as an intern since last summer at my current company (part-time this winter with class). I will be an intern full-time this summer, and I was wondering when should I ask my manager for a full-time offer (for January 2025) since I don't want to work part-time for my last semester (sept-december). It's a small company in the tech industry.

Should I start the discussion now, should I wait for the middle of the summer internship, or should I ask at the end?

Secondly,
if I do wait, should I apply elsewhere too and potentially use that to show I'm valuable?

I read [Is it appropriate to ask for a full-time offer after the end of my internship](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-a-fulltime-offer-after-the-end-of-my-internship?newreg=13bdcd81715849139726162ef5297458) however it's a very old post and at that time, tech was in employee market whereas now the market is very bad and saturated so the advice might defer.

I'm open to any advice and happy to clarify anything!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it appropriate to ask for a fulltime offer after the end of my internship?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-a-fulltime-offer-after-the-end-of-my-internship)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best advise:

Make your intentions clear from the outset.

If you would like to become a full-time employee, let them know that this is what you want.

*And then you ask what you can do to secure that position*

So for example - they might say 'pass this industry certification and we will consider you', they might give you a project to work on. You want to have an agreed set of actions that you can be responsible for, that will tip the balance in your favor.

*That said...*

You absolutely should be applying around, as far and as wide as you possibly can. You don't need to let them know you are doing it, but when if you do land an offer and you have other offers in hand - you are in a much better negotiating position than if you have no offers in hand.

Comment: Thank you so much that's a great answer! How do you recommend mentioning other offers to current employer ? I'm afraid it would appear threatening to them or show a lack of commitment like others answers mentioned.

Comment: @user - You don't, until it is negotiation time. They don't need to know before then.

Answer (score -3):

> Secondly, if I do wait, should I apply elsewhere too and potentially use that to show I'm valuable?

That shows your current employer that you have no loyalty to them and are thinking of leaving.  Not a good thing if you want your internship to become a permanent job.

You can look around for other employment if you wish, but there's no benefit to telling your current employer.

Answer (score -3):

Communiate your intent asap. Period. Do not hope for a lot - the market is awful right now, recession coming, depending where you are - well - there are plenty of hiring freezes and firing rounds open. You do not name a location - so I can not really advice based on that, but I know how bad things are, and I live in an area which is growing like mad. Still a bad market.

Search far and wide, but DO NOT COMMUNICATE THAT. This is a BAD idea. Your hand, your cards, showing them is not smart.